# What happens to units of values treated with sin, cos...?

Tags: trigonometry, logarithms, unit-of-measure

I know what happens when I compute a square root of 9 square metres - it's just 3 metres. But what about more weird cases, like:

- sqrt(4m) - square root of 4 metres - is it 2 square-roots-of-metres of some sort?
- sin(4m)
- log(4m)

For context:

I know that those values (and their units) probably don't make much sense in real world, but I'm wondering if a unit-aware all-purpose calculator can exist, and how it should react: should it disallow some operations, make values unitless as a result of some operations, or brute force the units somehow.

Imagine that you have a calculator that has buttons for metres, amperes, lumens, kelvins etc, as well as some SI derived units (newtons, ohms...) and maybe a bunch of unit-aware constants (c = 299 792 458 m/s). How would such calculator behave?

Comment: The arguments of sin, cos,  log and exponential cannot have units. This can be understood by the fact that they can be described by infinite series and then you cannot add units like m, m^2, m^3 etc.

Comment: When would you want to do these calculations? $\log(4m)$ in a sense would be $\log(4)+\log(m)$ and you might want to use this graphing values some of which were in metres and some in kilometres since $\log(km) = \log(1000)+\log(m)$ but it could be confusing - though decibels use a similar idea on power levels

Comment: Square-root actually IS a thing, see for example [Noise and what does V/√Hz actually mean?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/32257)

Comment: @henry, "When would you want to do these calculations?" - I don't know, it's not up to me, I'm trying to create a calculator. You cannot divide by zero and yet it's possible to input "5/0=" from the keypad and the result is "E" (Error). I'm trying to figure out when should my calculator respond with "E", when should it drop the units but proceed with numbers, etc.

Comment: @PawełLis - my calculator does not have a button for units such as *metres*, so would not allow me to attempt such a calculation

Comment: @Henry imagine that it does have that button, how would it behave? That's what this question is about

Comment: The calculator you imagine already exists. It is called Wolfram Alpha. Try it and find out what it does with units.